# Pandas: List of tuples with differing columns to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I've got data pulled from a database that is a list of tuples but the lists do not have a guaranteed format. The lists are actually composed of JSON like attribute:parameter combos:

```
example_data = [('ID1', 12 ,['Name','Age','Job'], ['John','33','Driver']),('ID2',21, ['Name', 'Car'], ['Jane', 'Honda'])]
```

What I want is a dataframe that populates the field but leaves the unknown fields as None's or NaN's:

```
example_DF =
   ID    IX   Name   Age  Job    Car
0  ID1   12   John   33   Driver -
1  ID2   21   Jane   -    -      Honda
```

currently doing a straight up pd.DataFrame(example_data) returns:

```
     0   1                 2                   3
0  ID1  12  [Name, Age, Job]  [John, 33, Driver]
1  ID2  21       [Name, Car]       [Jane, Honda]
```

which is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
import pandas as pd

example_data = [('ID1', 12 ,['Name','Age','Job'], ['John','33','Driver']),('ID2',21, ['Name', 'Car'], ['Jane', 'Honda'])]

l = []
for example in example_data:
    d = dict()
    d['id'] = example[0]
    d['row'] = example[1]
    for key, attribute in zip(example[2], example[3]):
        d[key] = attribute
    l.append(d)


df = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(df)

   Age    Car     Job  Name   id  row
0   33    NaN  Driver  John  ID1   12
1  NaN  Honda     NaN  Jane  ID2   21
```

It works if the format - the tuples are consistent. You could also check that the lists of descriptions and values have the same length.

Comment: yup, it works. The tuples are consistent; it's just the JSON'y bits that aren't. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
import pandas as pd

example_data = [('ID1', 12, ['Name', 'Age', 'Job'], ['John', '33', 'Driver']), ('ID2', 21, ['Name', 'Car'], ['Jane', 'Honda'])]

def change_dataframe():
    temp_list = []
    for data in example_data:
        temp_dict = {'ID': data[0], 'IX': data[1]}
        temp_dict.update(dict(zip(data[2], data[3])))
        temp_list.append(temp_dict)
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_list)

change_dataframe()
```